# Array object filter in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have a problem with Strapi filter so I would like to filter the tags array that have name equal to healthy following the first image

[image]

here is my code that uses qs to manage param the tags are an array.

[image]

but the result is incorrect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
url query will be ->   "/api/tags?filter[tags][name][$contains]=healthy"
```

qs will be like ->

```
 const qs = require('qs');
    const query = qs.stringify({
      filters: {
        tags:{
          name:{
            $contains: "healthy"
          }
        }
      },
    }, {
      encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify URL
    });
    
    await request(`/api/tags?${query}`);
```

Comment: It now works it occurs the error

Comment: I hope my answer did helped you, if you like you can upvote my answer. @china
thankyou